# The form editing the existing form does not save and redirects to wrong. Django

Tags: django, forms, model

I'm trying to add an edit form to an existing model, but it does not save every time and redirects me to the home page instead of the 'account' page. What am I doing wrong? why changes in the existing model are not visible? any help will be appreciated.

**views.py**

```
def account(request):
    data_now = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
    #my form
    time = get_object_or_404(Time, pk=52)
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = TimeEditForm(request.POST, instance=time)
        if form.is_valid():
            time = form.save(commit=False)
            time.save()
            return redirect('account')
    else:
        form = TimeEditForm(instance=time)


    context = {'data_now': data_now, 'time_edit_form': form}
    return render(request, 'account.html', context)
```

**forms.py**

```
class TimeEditForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Time
        fields = ('compartment',)
        labels ={
            'free_or_no': 'field name in my language?'
        }
```

**models.py**

```
class Time(models.Model):
    day_time = models.ForeignKey(DayTime, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    compartment = models.CharField(max_length=11)
    free_or_no = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    time_equivalent = models.IntegerField()
```

**urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.masseur_detail, name='masseur_detail'),
    url(r'^account$', views.account, name='account')
]
```

**account.html**

```
                <form action="." method="post">
                    {% csrf_token %}
                    {{ time_edit_form|crispy }}
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-block btn-primary"> Save</button>
                </form>
```

Comment: Please show the template.

Comment: And where is the rest of that view?

Comment: There isn't anything here that would send you to the home page. You'll need to give more details. What URL are you going to, to see the form? Is the form displayed correctly?

Comment: the form is displayed correctly, but when you edit it, no changes are made to the model. The address I want to always be visible to the form, after changing it or other activities in this place is only '/ account' I do not want to do anything on the home page.
Do you see what I'm doing wrong? Why are not changes in the model saved?

Comment: I'm sorry, I can't understand "The address I want to always be visible to the form, after changing it or other activities in this place is only '/ account".

Comment: after pressing the save button should not redirect to the main page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is quite a subtle issue.

Usually in Django it's recommended to use URLs that end with a slash - eg "/account/" - but your URL is just "/account", without the slash.

Now, when you put `action="."` in your form, the browser interprets this as "post to the root of the current directory". If your URL did end with a slash, that would be resolve to the same page. But because it doesn't, the browser posts to the root itself, ie "/".

The best solution is to change your URL pattern to `r'^account/$'`; alternatively (but not recommended) you could change your form to use `action=""`.